# How get value and text of selected item in dropdownlist on server&

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc

In model I have this propery

```
public List<SelectListItem> listikOFProducts = new List<SelectListItem>();
```

I fill it

```
var productList = from product in n.Products
                  select new { Name = product.ProductName, ID = product.ProductID };
foreach (var order in productList)
{
  newOrder.listikOFProducts.Add(new SelectListItem { Text = order.Name, Value = order.ID.ToString() });
}
```

In View I show it

```
<% using(Html.BeginForm("View2","Order"))
{  %>
  <div>
    <%: Html.DropDownList("drop",Model.listikOFProducts) %>
  </div>
  <input type="submit" name="button" value="Add" /> 
<% } %>
```

How I can get the text on selected item in dropdownlist in controller. The value of selected item in DropDownList I know.

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult View2(NorthOrder q, string button)
{
  if (button == "Add")
  {
    string strDDLValue = Request.Form["drop"].ToString();//ID of dropdown selected  item
    return View();
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use your id on the post method to get the value again

```
[HttpPost]
 public ActionResult View2(NorthOrder q,int drop, string button)
 {
              if (button == "Add")
       {
string strDDLValue= db.Products.FirstOrDefault(_=>_.ProductID == drop).ProductName;

                       return View();
   }
}
```

Comment: Ok. I can do it, but another way. if I correct understand I cant do it without query to db?

Comment: You can use javascript to set a value of a hidden field on dropdown change, but I dont think it would be a good practice